# Imported GoPro Hero4 time-lapse from bike ride does not sync with GPS data in VIRB Edit

Tags: time-lapse, gopro

I have imported a time-lapse (1 frame/sec resolution) video from my GoPro Hero4 into VIRB Edit. It's from a 96 minute bike ride, which shows up as a 4 minute video.

When I import GPS/GPX data from my Garmin Fenix 5, it does not align with the video. It sees it as a 4 minute bike ride.  (VIRB Edit use this data to make route overlays on the video.)

How to make VIRB Edit properly recognize the video as a time-lapse? Or how do I "compress" the GPX so that it matches the video?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imported time-lapse from bike ride does not sync with G-Metrix data in VIRB Edit](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29546/imported-time-lapse-from-bike-ride-does-not-sync-with-g-metrix-data-in-virb-edit)

Comment: @stib Nope, it was a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this is to first losslessly change the frame rate of the GoPro video to 1 frame/sec, which changes it from 4 minutes to real time (96 minutes).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465730/13365) explains how to extract the raw bitstream from the GoPro video using **ffmpeg**:

```
ffmpeg -y -i gopro.mp4 -c copy -f h264 gopro_raw.h264
```

.. and then remux it with a 1 frame/sec frame rate:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1 -i gopro_raw.h264 -c copy gopro_remuxed.mp4
```

Import the remuxed file into VIRB Edit [VE], add the GPX file and add some G-Metrix gauges.  Finally speed it up again in VE.

VE can only speed up 800%, so the video has to be re-imported***** after the initial export.  Speed it up and export again to come back to the original 4 minute length.  Not ideal, but it works.

<sub>***** I actually had to use iMovie in the second step, since VE kept crashing</sub>